# Template data via v-for

Tags: vue.js

how can I pick up the data in `likeNEW` via `v-for`. there you need to write `[0]  [1]`. you can do without them

```
Likelike(){
        axios
          .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer/like/', { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+ this.$store.state.accessToken } })
          .then((response) => {
        
            this.likeProduck=response.data
            console.log(response.data)
          })
          .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
           }
},
```

**template**

```
<li class="clearfix" v-for="item in likeProduck" :key="item.id" >
```

[image]

Comment: You just have to call `{{item.likeNew.id}}` inside the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one from below

```
<li class="clearfix" v-for="({ likeNew }) in likeProduck" :key="item.id">
{{ likeNew.img1 }}  // ur stuffs
</li>
```

or

```
<li class="clearfix" v-for="({ likeNew }, index) in likeProduck" :key="index">
{{ likeNew.img1 }}  // ur stuffs
</li>
```